# two fortran questions

Tags: fortran

1. Is there any way for gfortran to compile a f90 program but with a non-f90 extension, or even no file extension at all?
2. How to suppress pause statement warning used in a f90 program when compiled with gforTRan?

Many thanks.

---

1. gfortran -c sourfile.xyz does not work. I know the manpage explains these options, but I did not find one working.
2. I mean in my f90 program, I have a pause statement. If I compile it, I got a warning saying the use of pause is obsolete. I want to suppress this warning during compilation.

Comment: Dont use `pause`, it is not well defined and rightly deleted (not only obsolete). If you want to stop and force a keyboard action, write a `pause` subroutine and use `read(*,*)` or equivalent inside.

Comment: Sometimes I hate the Archeology badge because of these really old posts popping up...

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppress all warnings with -w option?